# MongoDB select optional fields or defaults if exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i try to select a document with some optional i18n properties.
That means i like to recive a few properties of the document and if exsits all "de" properties of the "localized" property.
For a better understanding, the document in the DB looks like this.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("643926af14c8821ad40f8b47"),
  "price" : 1.256,
  "vendor" : "Any Company",
  "blocked" : false
  "localized" : {
        "en" : {
          "name" : "water carafe",
          "description" : "Contents: 1x ... up closure."
        },
        "de" : {
          "name" : "Wasserkaraffe",
          "description" : "Inhalt: 1x ... up-Verschluss."
        },
        "nm" : {
          "name" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          "description" : "At vero eo ... o duo dolores."
        }
    },
  "PropertyB" : 124,
  "SomePropertyC" : "importen property"
}
```

But i'm only interested at this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("643926af14c8821ad40f8b47"),
  "price" : 1.256,
  "localized" : {
        "de" : {
          "name" : "Wasserkaraffe",
          "description" : "Inhalt: 1x ... up-Verschluss."
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that I only want to select a few root fields and the "de" fields. If "de" is not available, "en" should be selected and returned. And should it be possible, if both cases are not present, that the first best one is returned, then it would be unbelievable. At the end i transform the document into a flattet new one

At the end

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("643926af14c8821ad40f8b47"),
  "price" : 1.256,
  "localized" : {
        "de" : {
          "name" : "Wasserkaraffe",
          "description" : "Inhalt: 1x ... up-Verschluss."
        }
    }
}
```

At the end I convert the document into a flat new one. The $project (aggregation) is apparently provided for this. This works quite well so far. However, the query of the document is not possible for me.
Does anyone have an idea how this could work?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      price: 1,
      localized: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $not: [ "$localized.de" ] },
          then: { en: "$localized.en" },
          else: { de: "$localized.de" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IXRC0C2BamE)

---

If both "de" and "en" are missing, then we take the first one that comes along.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      price: 1,
      localized: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $not: [ "$localized.de" ] },
          then: { "$cond": {
              if: { $not: [ "$localized.en" ] },
              then: { $arrayToObject: { $slice: [{ $setUnion: { $objectToArray: "$localized" }}, 1]}},
              else: { en: "$localized.en" }
            }
          },
          else: { de: "$localized.de" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zgiHh8715L_)